# multi-character constant при использовании кириллицы в map

Tags: c++, ubuntu, map, g++

Я хочу сделать словарь, чтобы использовать его в цикле и менять введенный текст посимвольно, сравнивая его со словарём, но у меня выдает ошибку **multi-character constant**

*P.S. если заменить ключи на английские буквы, то всё работает нормально, но мне нужен русский; замена кавычек с ординарных на двойные так же не делает никакой погоды; смена char на string тоже не помогла.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    map <char, string> fontDictionary = 
    {
        {'а', "А"}, 
        {'б', "6"},
        {'в', "B"},
        {'г', "G"},
        {'д', "D"},
        {'е', "E"},
        {'ё', "E"},
        {'ж', "}I{"},
        {'з', "3"},
        {'и', "U"},
        {'й', "u"},
        {'к', "K"},
        {'л', "JI"},
        {'м', "M"},
        {'н', "H"},
        {'о', "O"},
        {'п', "II"},
        {'р', "P",},
        {'с', "C"},
        {'т', "T"},
        {'у', "y"},
        {'ф', "o|o"},
        {'х', "X"},
        {'ц', "Ul"},
        {'ч', "4"},
        {'ш', "W"},
        {'щ', "W"},
        {'ъ', "b"},
        {'ы', "bI"},
        {'ь', "b"},
        {'э', "e"},
        {'ю', "IO"},
        {'я', "9"}, 
    };

    string toBeChanged;
    cin >> toBeChanged;

    return 0;
}
```

Код ошибки в терминале:

```
grxxndxxm@grxxndxxm:~/Desktop$ g++ CS16Font.cpp -o CS16
CS16Font.cpp:13:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   13 |         {'а', "А"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:14:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   14 |         {'б', "6"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:15:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   15 |         {'в', "B"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:16:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   16 |         {'г', "G"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:17:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   17 |         {'д', "D"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:18:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   18 |         {'е', "E"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:19:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   19 |         {'ё', "E"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:20:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   20 |         {'ж', "}I{"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:21:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   21 |         {'з', "3"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:22:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   22 |         {'и', "U"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:23:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   23 |         {'й', "u"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:24:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   24 |         {'к', "K"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:25:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   25 |         {'л', "JI"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:26:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   26 |         {'м', "M"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:27:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   27 |         {'н', "H"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:28:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   28 |         {'о', "O"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:29:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   29 |         {'п', "II"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:30:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   30 |         {'р', "P",},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:31:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   31 |         {'с', "C"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:32:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   32 |         {'т', "T"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:33:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   33 |         {'у', "y"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:34:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   34 |         {'ф', "o|o"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:35:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   35 |         {'х', "X"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:36:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   36 |         {'ц', "Ul"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:37:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   37 |         {'ч', "4"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:38:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   38 |         {'ш', "W"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:39:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   39 |         {'щ', "W"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:40:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   40 |         {'ъ', "b"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:41:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   41 |         {'ы', "bI"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:42:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   42 |         {'ь', "b"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:43:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   43 |         {'э', "e"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:44:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   44 |         {'ю', "IO"},
      |          ^~~~
CS16Font.cpp:45:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   45 |         {'я', "9"},
      |          ^~~~
```

Comment: *"смена char на string тоже не помогла"* - а должна была, так что я не верю

Comment: Попробовал вставить в Qt (ничего другого под рукой нет). Выдает такую же ошибку. Но если заменить строчные буквы на английский или поставить двойные кавычки - ошибка пропадает. Правда, текст ошибки слегка другой: ```ошибка: character too large for enclosing character literal type ```

Comment: Замена char на string и одинарных кавычек на двойные тоже помогла. Если просто заменить все кавычки, ругается на несоответствие типов

Comment: Русские буквы в utf8 занимают два байта и в однобайтовый char очевидно не влезают

Comment: Скорее всего, дело именно в этом.  Не ругается на вот такую запись: ```{L'а', "А"}```

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов да, спасибо, добавление {L'а', "А"} помогло, но при компиляции и выполнении дальше у меня почему-то не выполняется код (cin после map). Оно просто не даёт ввод.

Comment: Проверил у себя. Нормально вводится строка. Что значит - не дает ввод?